# android align Input text dialog in textview

Tags: android, dialog, alignment

I have an android app where the user can enter his name and another information through dialog inside a text view. the problem is if the user entered his name in English the name will be in the left of the page and if another user entered his name in Arabic the name will be in the right.

and I am looking for a way to make the name align to be always in the right whether the user entered his in English or Arabic.

here is my code:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

     alert.setTitle("Title");
     alert.setMessage("Message");

     // Set an EditText view to get user input 
     final EditText input = new EditText(this);
     alert.setView(input);

     alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
       Editable value = input.getText();

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_id);

         tv.setText("" + value);


     }
     });

     alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
         // Canceled.
       }
     });

 alert.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one:-

```
 // Set an EditText view to get user input 
 final EditText input = new EditText(this);

   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
   lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
   input.setLayoutParams(lp);
   alert.setView(input);

 alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
   Editable value = input.getText();

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mj);
     tv.setText("" + value);
 }
 });
```

please let me know if it works or not :)